# Thread Options MariaDB Sql Injection syntax to use near

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb, ezsql

I have tried sql injection my script. I have a problem in ezSQL.

Original query

```
$dbo->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE id = '1'");
```

Injected Query

```
$dbo->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE id = '1'; SELECT * FROM table -- -'");
```

Error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT * FROM table -- -' at line 1
```

But,

This Sql Query works phpmyadmin SQL Command successfully. I dont understand this. Why sql code doesnt work in ezsql query?
Please help me.

Comment: ezsql has an escape method, but frankly, if it doesn't have an easy way to parameterize queries, then don't use it. Use PDO or mysqli instead.

Comment: Probably it doesn't let you send more than one query at a time. Most PHP API's wont.

Comment: So in this case, sql injection not able ?

Comment: Sure it is.  Just not like this.

Comment: So, does it have any way to sql injection?